# Add FBA User using C#

Tags: development, sharepoint-server, forms-authentication

I have install the FBA SharePoint 2013 pack.

https://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/

It's configured and working.

What I am trying to do is programmatically add a FBA user.

Has anyone done this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can grab the code from the FBA Pack:

https://sharepoint2013fba.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication/Visigo.Sharepoint.FormsBasedAuthentication/Layouts/FBA/MANAGEMENT/UserNew.aspx.cs

Comment: Can you use this code from a Console application? MembershipUser user = Utils.BaseMembershipProvider().GetUser(loginName, false)

Comment: It should with some changes to BaseMembershipProvider() - as this gets the current sharepoint context - which you won't have on the command line.  You'll have to specify the membership provider yourself - but you can do that with the web.config file if it's a seperate console application.